# Determining derivative penalization for hierarchical GAM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to fit 4 hierarchical GAMs to my dataset and compare them to determine the best-fit model.  I have been relying on [Pedersen et al 2019](https://peerj.com/articles/6876) to help me specify these models, but I don't think I fully grasp setting `m` for each smooth.

My dataset has the following variables: year, region, site, and mass. Sites are nested under region.

In the first two models, I'm interested in comparing the trend in mass across sites with the same smoothness/wiggliness and the with the same smoothness, but different wiggliness. In these models, the global trend is across all sites. These are basically taken exactly out of [Pedersen et al 2019](https://peerj.com/articles/6876), so I'm pretty confident that they are correct.

```
# 1. a) Global trend across all sites, same wiggliness [equivalent to GS in Pederson et al. 2019]
mGS <- gam(mass ~ s(year, bs = "tp", k = 10, m = 2) +                       # global trend, m = 2
                  s(year, site, bs = "fs", k = 10, m = 2),                  # site trend, m = 2
            data = df, method = "ML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))  # used ML instead of REML for model comparison

# 1. b) Global trend across all sites, different wiggliness [equivalent to GI in Pederson et al. 2019]
mGI <- gam(mass ~ s(year, bs = "tp", k = 10) +                              # global trend
                  s(year, by = site, bs = "tp", k = 10, m = 1) +            # site trend, m = 1
                  s(site, bs = "re"),                                       # random effect for site
            data = df, method = "ML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))
```

However, for the second set of models, instead of the global trend across all sites, I want to set a regional trend, and I'm not entirely sure I've set the `m` parameter correctly, especially in 2b) where `m = 1` for both the regional and site smooths.

```
# 2. a) Regional trend for nested sites, same wiggliness
mRS <- gam(mass~ s(year, by = region, bs = "tp", k = 10, m = 1) +              # regional smooth, m = 1 similar to site trend in model 1b)
                 s(region, bs = "re") +                                        # random effect for region similar to 1b)
                 s(year, site, bs = "fs", k = 10, m = 2),                      # site trend, m = 2 similar to site trend in model 1a)
            data = means, method = "ML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))  

# 2. b) Regional trend for nested sites, different wiggliness
mRI <- gam(mass ~ s(year, by = region, bs = "tp", k = 10, m = 1) +             # regional smooth, m = 1 similar to site trend in model 1b)
                  s(region, bs = "re") +                                       # random effect for region similar to model 1b)
                  s(year, by = site, bs = "tp", k = 10, m = 1) +               # site trend, m = 1 similar to site trend in model 1b)
                  s(site, bs = "re"),                                          # random effect for site
            data = means, method = "ML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `m = 1` (first derivative penalty) on the factor `by` smooths is to make the factor `by` smooths *identifiable* from what we called the "global" smooth. If you don't have a global smooth then you really don't need `m = 1` and are best to use the default second order derivative penalty.

To be clear, when I'm talking about a global smooth I mean the term `s(x)` in the following model:

```
y ~ f + s(x) + s(x, by = f, m = 1)
```

In both of your regional models you don't have the equivalent of `s(x)` so I would suggest that `m = 2` be used otherwise you'll be fitting functions that aren't visually smooth.

Since we wrote the HGAM paper, Simon Wood has added a constrained factor smooth basis that provides a better way to fit a HGAM with a global smooth plus (the equivalent of) `by` factor smooths, the `bs = "sz"` basis. This basis is made properly orthogonal to the global smooth, so we don't need to worry about the distinctions of what `m` to use.

Such a model would be fitted as

```
y ~ s(x) + s(x, f, bs = "sz")
```

noting that we don't need the parametric (or the random intercept) for factor `f`.

So your model 1b could be fitted as

```
mGI <- gam(mass ~ s(year, bs = "tp", k = 10) +
                  s(year, site, bs = "sz", k = 10),
            data = df, method = "ML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))
```

And your model 2b might run into issues because you have multiple smooths of `year`, which might not be so identifiable. Instead, you could use the `"sz"` basis to fit a global smooth and then properly orthogonal "difference" smooths for each site and region:

```
mRI <- gam(mass ~ s(year) +
                  s(year, region, bs = "sz", k = 10) +
                  s(year, site, bs = "sz", k = 10),
            data = means, method = "ML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4))
```

While we described these models in terms of

1. global + subject specific smooth, or
2. subject specific smooths with no common smooth

each model is trying to estimate the smooth effect of `year` on the response for each level of a factor. The different models decompose the variation in the response into different sets of smooth functions. Option 1. can be efficient if there is common shape to the subject-specific effects of `year` and if that is part of the research question. But you can use either model to fit your data and even if you don't think there is a global effect, you can use that model in the 2b setting if it helps solve computational issues with the ideal or prefered approach.

Comment: thanks for that detailed answer and providing an example of using the "sz" basis.